# c++ program with 2 classes

Tags: c++, object-oriented, classes

Im making this project from few days , and now i need little help because i am struggling.
The task says

II. Define a student booklet class CStudBook that inherits CStudent with a member data container of the student's grades. To implement a constructor with a filename parameter from which to initialize container and the following methods:

```
Create an object using another object (copy constructor)
Creating an object using explicit parameters
Creating an object by default constructor
Calculate and return the student's grade point average
operator>>
operator<<
Print
```

I created almost everything , but i cannot find a way to output the student grade from my 2nd class into the console. I will drop the code.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <vector> 
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class CStudent {
public:
    // Default constructor
    CStudent() = default;

    // Explicit constructor
    CStudent(string name, int facnum, string specialty) {
        this->name = name;
        this->facnum = facnum;
        this->specialty = specialty;
    }

    // Copy constructor
    CStudent(const CStudent& obj) {
        this->name = obj.name;
        this->facnum = obj.facnum;
        this->specialty = obj.specialty;
    }

    // Method, that prints the contents of the object
    void PrintStudent() const {
        cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
        cout << "Fac. num: " << facnum << endl;
        cout << "Specialty: " << specialty << endl;
    }
   
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const CStudent& obj) // output operator
    {
        out << "Name:" << obj.name << "-> FacNumber: " << obj.facnum << std::endl;

    }

  

    bool operator <(const CStudent& obj) // operator for comparison of two objects
    {
        return name < obj.name;
        return facnum < obj.facnum;
        
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, CStudent& obj) // operator za vhod
    {
        in >> obj.name;
        in >> obj.facnum;
        in >> obj.specialty;

     }

    private:
    string name;
    int facnum;
    string specialty;
    
};

class CStudBook : public CStudent {
private:
    int grade;
    
public:
    CStudBook()
    {
    }
 
    CStudBook(int grade)
    {
        this->grade = grade;
    }

    CStudBook(const CStudBook& obj) {

        this->grade = obj.grade;
    }
    void PrintCStudBook() const {
        cout << "Grade of student: " << grade << endl;
         }
 



};
 
  















// Function, that gets student data from the console
// and creates an instance of the CStudent class using this data
CStudent CreateFromConsole() {
    cout << "Enter name: ";
    string name;
    cin >> name;

    cout << "Enter fac. num: ";
    int facnum;
    cin >> facnum;

    cout << "Enter specialty: ";
    string specialty;
    cin >> specialty;

    cout << endl;
    return CStudent(name, facnum, specialty); // returns an instance of the class
    

}





int main() {
    vector<CStudent> students; // stack-like container

    cout << "Enter total number of students: ";
    int count;
    cin >> count;

    cout << "Enter details of students" << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        // Create an instance of the class
        CStudent student = CreateFromConsole();
       
        // Push a copy of the object into the container
        students.push_back(student);




    }

    cout << endl;

    cout << "Details" << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
        students[i].PrintStudent();
        cout << endl;
    }

    fflush(stdin); // Reset input console 
    getchar(); // Pause
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The task is flawed. Inheritance should be "is a" relation, but "Student booklet is a student" is false. [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) will not work here. Of course, it's up to your tutor to teach you, but pay attention to this.
2. You have PrintStudent() and PrintCStudBook() methods together with operator<<.
   std::cout<<student;
   should probably do the same as
   student.PrintStudent();
   so those methods are excessive.
3. Use class members initialization (via :).
4. Use const references for class arguments like std::string.
5. Class members usually have some mark in their name to distinguish them from other variables - like name_ or m_name instead of name.
6. Task says "member data container of the student's grades" - and you have only single int, not a container.
7. "To implement a constructor with a filename parameter" - can't find it. Btw this is against [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).
8. Now to your question. You should have an object of your second class (CStudBook) to output it; then you should call PrintCStudBook on that object. Probably, you should also add a way to initialize the inherited data members of CStudBook with students data (like the constructor with Student argument).

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please refrain from answering low-quality questions that are likely to get closed.  Once you've answered, that [limits what can be done to improve the question](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body), making it more likely that your efforts are wasted.  It's better to wait until the question is properly ready before you answer!